# tkinter `OptionMenu` first option is repeated (shown twice)

Tags: python, tkinter

I find it quite confusing, but I do have a working solution (see my question/problem further down).

Functional description: update the label on menu selection change. Use tk variables.

[image]

```Python
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font


def UpdateLabel(TheRoot):
    """When changing the dropdown box, update the label"""
    Theoption = TheRoot.getvar(name="TheChoice")
    TheRoot.setvar(name="CurrentlyUsing", value=f"Currently using: {Theoption}")

def main():
    r = tk.Tk()
    r.title("Configure")
    mainframe = tk.Frame(r)
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=2)   
    mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    mainframe.pack(pady=40, padx=60)

    MyFont = font.Font(family='Helvetica', size=14) # Common font for all widgets
    optionTypes = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

    # Define TK variables
    TheChosen_option = tk.StringVar(master=mainframe, name="TheChoice", value=optionTypes[0])
    TheMessageString = tk.StringVar(master=mainframe, name="CurrentlyUsing", value=f"Currently using: {optionTypes[0]}")

    # Dropdown box of options
    DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, TheChosen_option, optionTypes[0], *optionTypes[1:], command=lambda _: UpdateLabel(r))
    DropDown.grid(row=1, column=1)
    DropDown.config(font=MyFont)  # DropDown widget font
    menu = mainframe.nametowidget(DropDown.menuname)
    menu.config(font=MyFont) # DropDown menu font

    # footer text of current selection
    tk.Label(master=mainframe, textvariable=TheMessageString, font=MyFont).grid(row=2, column=1)

    r.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

My question is why the first option comes twice, if the following row is replaced from:

```Python
DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, TheChosen_option, optionTypes[0], *optionTypes[1:], command=lambda _: UpdateLabel(r))
```

to

```Python
DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, TheChosen_option, optionTypes[0], *optionTypes, command=lambda _: UpdateLabel(r))
```

(e.g.  `*optionTypes[1:]` to  `*optionTypes`)

"a" is shown twice. The compiler tells me I must have the third "value" argument in `tk.OptionMenu()`. So from my understanding, the "value" argument is added first, and then the list itself? Therefore, I have passed the list starting from the second index (in the main code snippet).

This seems like it is a bit over complicated, and could be done in a simpler way? And I know global variables could be used, but I would like to keep it to local variables only.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See the parameters of the `OptionMenu`](https://tkdocs.com/shipman/optionmenu.html):

```
w = tk.OptionMenu(parent, variable, choice1, choice2, ...)
```

[Understand unpack `*` in python](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/)

---

In your code:

```
DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, TheChosen_option, optionTypes[0], *optionTypes[1:], command=lambda _: UpdateLabel(r))
```

`mainframe` mean the container of this widget, variable is the `StringVar`.And the remains(except `command=....`) are variables could be selected in `OptionMenu`.So that mean `optionTypes[0], *optionTypes[1:]` are the selections.

Basically, The value of `optionTypes[0], *optionTypes[1:]` and `*optionTypes` are the same.

But the second example:

```
DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, TheChosen_option, optionTypes[0], *optionTypes, command=lambda _: UpdateLabel(r))
```

The selections are `optionTypes[0] + optionTypes`.And that's why `a` would show twice.

Comment: Thanks, that `*` unpacking link thought me something new . I can no longer reproduce the initial compiler error, that I got. So perhaps there was something else wrong with my code. Thanks for your reply! 

Answer (score 2):

> My question is why the first option comes twice, if the following row is replaced from ... *optionTypes[1:] to  *optionTypes "a" is shown twice.

The reason is because making the change causes you to pass the first value twice, and the tk `OptionMenu` will add it to the menu twice since that's how it's designed to work.

The problem is likely due to you confusing the ttk `OptionMenu` with the tk `OptionMenu`. Unfortunately, they have slightly different APIs. If you're using a wildcard import, or copying code from one file or website into another file, you may be using the syntax of the ttk `OptionMenu` with the tk `OptionMenu`.

The ttk OptionMenu class uses the first positional parameter after the variable as the default value. The tk OptionMenu does not. Thus, the exact same usage will yield different results depending on which OptionMenu you use.

In other words, the tk `OptionMenu` should be called like this:

```
tk.OptionMenu(parent, var, "a", "b", "c", "d")
```

whereas the ttk `OptionMenu` should be called like this (assuming you want "a" to be the default value)

```
ttk.OptionMenu(parent, var, "a", "a", "b", "c", "d")
```

If you try using the second form with a tk `OptionMenu`, you'll see "a" repeated twice in the menu.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use OptionMenu without setting default value:

```py
DropDown = tk.OptionMenu(mainframe, TheChosen_option, *optionTypes, command=lambda _: UpdateLabel(r))
```

Comment: well that's strange. That worked now. Before, the compiler was telling that I couldn't run the code without the `value` argument. I have no Idea what was wrong before.  Thanks. **EDIT:** now I only get a Pylint message `No value for argument 'value' in constructor call`

Comment: Yes that's very strange, I don't know too :)

Comment: That's not default value.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA oh, really. But anyway solution is the same :)